# bash script failing to match files as expected

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have written a small bash* script to process files in a directory. The files have a specific naming convention, which determines how the file is to be processed.

The filename starts with a geographic origin, and then contains a keyword in the filename that determines how it should be processed.

Here is the stripped down version of my script:

```
DATA_DIRECTORY=./data

array=( 'uk' 'usa' 'fra' 'ukr' )

for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    echo "#################################################"
    echo "Loop index : $i"
    echo "#################################################"

    # process baboon data for the current country
    for filename in $DATA_DIRECTORY/$i_*_baboon*.csv; do
       echo "Processing file: $filename in loop: $i"
    done

    # process whale data for the current country
    for filename in $DATA_DIRECTORY/$i_*_whale*.csv; do
       echo "Processing file: $filename in loop: $i"
    done

    # process lion data for the current country
    for filename in $DATA_DIRECTORY/$i_*_lion*.csv; do
       echo "Processing file: $filename in loop: $i"
    done

done
```

I am expecting the script above to match the files in the following way: A file named **us_2007_deaths_caused_by_baboon.csv** will be processed once - when the loop counter variable is 'us' and during the loop `for filename in $DATA_DIRECTORY/$i_*_baboon*.csv;`. However, the matching is not working as I expected, and each (nested for loop) is looping over all of the files in the directory - which is **NOT** what I want.

How may I pattern match the files based on the filenames?

*Note: I am using bash version 4.1.5 on Ubuntu 10.0.4

Comment: Would it not be the same to do it the way it's being done? The way it searches it will run through the entire list once, and remove lets say all of array[0] files. Then all of array[1] so on. If you have 100 files and each of the array[0-3] are an exact quarter (25 of each of them). It will search check 100x 75x 50x 25x. 250 comparisons. If you check them (file1 = array[0-3]) you will have 400-25-50-75 = 250 comparisons. Did I mess something up, it's late, if I did I'm sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write `${i}_` instead of `$i_` because `$i_` is "" (bash thinks that `i_` is a variable here).

For example:

```
for filename in $DATA_DIRECTORY/${i}_*_baboon*.csv; do
   echo "Processing file: $filename in loop: $i"
done
```

Comment: I'm shaking my head in disbelief.. I wasted one day over THIS?! Thanks anyway - problem is solved!.

Comment: +1, Quotes would be even better. Works fine for these known values though.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `${i}` instead of `$i` because `$i_*` will be parsed as variable `i_` instead of `i`.